# Different build result between npm and pnpm

Tags: typescript, npm, typescript-typings, pnpm, ts-loader

Recently, I have used `pnpm` instead of `npm` in the program. I built the project(`pnpm run build`) and received a ts error. (ts-loader in the webpack) It seems a TS error. but when I used `npm` it didn't throw errors(`npm run build`). Is there any difference between `pnpm` and `npm` cli?

```
export enum NormalisableDataType {
  A,
  B,
  C,
  D
}
...
const rawPollutantValueBands = {
  [`${NormalisableDataType.D}`]: 'sth'
};
...

export function normaliseRawReadingsToDysonAirQualityLevel(
  dataType: NormalisableDataType
) {
  const currentValueBands = dataType[normalisableDataType];
  ...
}
```

error message is **Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'NormalisableDataType' can't be used to index type '{ 3: string; }'.**
It seems a right TS check error.